# Gentile Studying Moshiach Predictions

Tags: messiah, noachide-laws

Is a gentile (by the seven laws) forbidden from hearing Moshiach predictions? If someone has a quote from the Zohar that supposedly shows when Moshiach will come, am I allowed to read it?

Comment: Even full-fledged Jews are advised to go easy on that stuff, to be honest. Maimonides writes that everybody keeps trying to predict when and it really doesn't do much for religious growth. "Those who keep trying to calculate this should be blasted."

Comment: This being said, there is no prohibition per se of reading this material. Just remember that "those who speak don't know, and those who know don't speak"